# You are flying an IFR trip in a Cessna 172 and you receive a pilot report (PIREP). It is useful if:

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, faa-knowledge-test

Practicing for my IFR written test. Question is in the title. Three options:

- A) It is current and reported by a similar airplane to your own.
- B) The report is given by a professional pilot—for example a Boeing 747.
- C) The pilot is reporting icing conditions and is flying a jet
  airplane.

I would have thought the correct answer is C because if a jet is reporting icing, the 172 will also have trouble. But apparently the correct answer is A, which I guess is also correct but in my view less useful if it's not reporting anything. What am I missing?

Comment: I know less than you but it could be because the jet pilot is flying higher or flying in IFR while you are in VFR

Comment: Don't worry about it, some of the FAA written test questions don't make much sense.

Comment: You can rule out B because Boeing 747s are not actually "pilots".  ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Flying a single-engine Cessna, you are unlikely to benefit from a PIREP provided by a plane flying 25 000 ft above your cruising conditions.

There is usually some trickery involved in [FAA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Aviation_Administration)/[EASA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Union_Aviation_Safety_Agency) tests. It may be that a [747](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_747) provides a PIREP while climbing, thus being helpful to you, but in most cases PIREPs from jets are not that helpful for single-engine piston aircraft.

<sub>As general advice, make sure you read the questions carefully, and understand what it is they are asking. Some of the questions are such that all of the options appear correct, and others may be such that none of the options seem correct. You have to pick the one that is most right or  not wrong in any aspect. It's all about context.</sub>

Answer (score 8):

(A) makes sense because the other two options are a bit open ended. (A) has all the information you need to judge whether it's a potential correct answer or not. If the 747 is above the FZ LVL, you don't need to worry about that (unless you take your skyhawk above FZ LVL and in visible moisture- then you should!). No matter what the PIREP always has to be current. Also, how **professional** the pilot is in general and proficient in giving PIREPs don't necessarily depend on what A/C they fly.

Agreeing with [Jpe61](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/102302/43980), as a pilot you're **primarily** looking for information that pertains to your flight. Read the PIREP (or any other Wx report for that matter) and see what information pertains to your type, altitude, route, etc., of flight.

However, that does not always mean that just because the information doesn't directly point toward your area of concern you should ignore it. You can always take every small bit of information to construct a broader, general "big picture" of what's going on in the skies and that's what your job is as a pilot. Something happening way above you might give you some ideas to what could follow in the next couple of hours at your flight level.
..

From an exam POV: in Canada, TC has a lot of questions where more than 1 option makes sense but they want us to select the option that makes the most sense for our scenario or in certain cases will give us the least bad outcome/most chances of survival.

Most (if not all) aviation exams focus on practical thinking. So, if the answer's not that straightforward, think about what you would do in a real world scenario like that.

Answer (score 3):

I would say that the correct answer is A)

First off, you need a pilot report to be current because it is as an onsite weather report of what’s going on in a specific location in space at a specific time. It’s not much help to you if the report was made two days ago. Second, a pilot report made by a pilot in an aircraft similar to yours is far more useful to you, because it’s going to be a similar configuration, wing loading and planform, similar airfoils, similar performance characteristics, similar onboard systems, and similar operating altitudes and airspeeds to your own aircraft.  This is important for dangerous kinds of weather such as thunderstorms, icing, windshear, turbulence, etc.  While a PIREP made by a professional pilot in a large jet is nice, it may not be relatable to your situation for the reasons given above, and, so long as it follows the correct format, will provide you with the same information any other pilot can provide, professional or not.  Therefore we would rule out B). The same applies to answer C).  While a PIREP that contains information about icing conditions can be useful to you, it may not be relevant to you in a Cessna 150 cruising at 4500 feet and well below the freezing level when it pertains to icing conditions encountered at 16,000 feet at 380 KTAS.  Therefore, we eliminate answer C), leaving A) as the correct answer.